# Make popup show as per current date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a [website](http://dundaah.com) that is keen on current dates. I have an email subscription popup that I want to display as per the current date.

```js
var $box2 = $('.box2');

$('.closei2').each(function() {
  var color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
  var content = $(this).html();
  $(this).click(function() {
    $box2.css('backgroundColor', color);
    $box2.addClass('open');
    $box2.find('p').html(content);
  });

  $('.close').click(function() {
    $box2.removeClass('open');
    $box2.css('backgroundColor', 'transparent');

  });

  $('body').toggleClass('overlay2');
  $("#pop-toggle").click(function() {
    $(".popup0").toggle();
    $('body').toggleClass('overlay2');
  })
  $(".close").click(function() {
    $(".popup0").toggle();
    $('body').toggleClass('overlay2');
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="popScroll">
  <div class="popup0">
    <h1>Subscribe for more</h1>
    <div class="subscribe-widget">
      <form id="subscribe-form" action="subscribe.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="cf_email" placeholder="Your Email Please" class="email-form" required>
        <button type="submit" class="button">Subscribe</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <p>Leave us your email for event updates & more</p>
    <div id="option">
      <a href="#" id="home" class="boxi2">Home</a> 
      <em>or</em>
      <a href="#" id="close" class="boxi2 closei2 close">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My date picker,

```js
//friday code
var d = new Date();
var s = d.getDay();
if (s == 4) {
  //execute popup;
}
```

I've tried combining the two to no avail. Where I'm I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is execute popup working without this date thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your javascript a bit and kept your HTML for reference, have a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/zzu22njs/

Javascript:

```
var $popup = $('.popScroll')

$popup
  .find('a.close')
  .on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $popup.hide();
  });

var now = new Date();

// Open on Fridays
if (now.getDay() === 5) {    
  $popup.show();
}
```

CSS:

```
.popScroll {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML: Same as before

Hopefully that will give you something to build on. I have only linked up the close link.

Comment: Hey Rick your code is awesome on jsfiddle but refuses to work once I run it on notepad++

Comment: becuase of the display none, it wont show, then if i remove display none, it still shows when now.getDay() === 4

Comment: The `display:none` is what keeps it hidden on days you don't want. If your javascript is before the html, then make sure you have it inside a `$(document).ready(function() { //in here });` or put it as the last thing in `<body>`

Comment: perfect! I added it before </body> and it worked! thank you very much, appreciate the help.